# Find rows in a file which doesnt contain a string and add text at start of it

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I have data in below format in a file.

```
name,path:A:B
loc:D
name,for:B:C
```

I need to add " ," (space + comma ) at start of all those lines which doesn't have , in it in the file to get the output like below.

```
name,path:A:B
 ,loc:D
name,for:B:C
```

`grep "[^,]" file` .. This gives me list of lines which doesnt contain , but I am not able to add at start .

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: grep "[^,]" file .. This gives me list of lines which doesnt contain  , but I am not able to add at start .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` is not the tool here, I'd use awk or sed. Using awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","  # set delimiters to ,
}
NF==1 {         # if there is only one field (consider NF<=1 for ampty records)
    $1=OFS $1   # add a delimiter in front of it
}
1' file         # output
```

Output:

```
name,path:A:B
,loc:D
name,for:B:C
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '!/,/{print OFS","$0;next} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '               ##Starting awk program from here.
!/,/{               ##Checking condition if line is NOT having comma then do following.
  print OFS","$0    ##Printing OFS comma and current line here.
  next              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                   ##1 will print current line here.
' Input_file        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -r '/\,/!s/(^.*$)/ ,\1/' file
```

Search for lines without a comma by using ! and then substitute the whole line for a space, comma and the existing line.

Comment: can be simplified to `sed '/\,/!s/^/ ,/'` (also, `-E` is more commonly used these days across implementations instead of `-r`)

Comment: Or just `sed '/,/!s/^/ ,/' file`; no need for EREs or capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
name,path:A:B
loc:D
name,for:B:C
```

then

```
awk '{print /,/?$0:" ,"$0}' file.txt
```

output

```
name,path:A:B
 ,loc:D
name,for:B:C
```

Explanation: for every line if there is `,` just `print` that line (`$0`) otherwise `print` concatenation of space-comma (`" ,"`) and that line (`$0`).

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

You could use `index` to check for a comma.

```
awk '{print index($0, ",") ? $0 : " ," $0}' file
```

Output

```
name,path:A:B
 ,loc:D
name,for:B:C
```

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of good answers using `sed` or `awk` here, which are perfectly fine to do that (even better than the following one). But just for fun, here is a `bash` only solution (without needing to invoke external programs like `grep` or whatever) which also do the trick:

```
$ while read -r; do p=""; [[ ! $REPLY =~ [^,]*\,[^,]* ]] && p=" ,"; echo "${p}${REPLY}"; done < test.txt 
name,path:A:B
 ,loc:D
name,for:B:C
```

The explained version:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r; do # looping over a file the right way in bash
  p="" # initializing a prefix
  [[ ! $REPLY =~ [^,]*\,[^,]* ]] && p=" ," # if the line doesn't contain a comma, the prefix will contain a comma
  echo "${p}${REPLY}"; # print the line with the prefix which can be blank or not
done < test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

To edit the file itself, use `ed`:

```
printf "%s\n" "v/,/s/^/ ,/" w | ed -s file
```

inserts a space and comma at the start of every line that doesn't already have a comma, and then saves the modified file.